# Process Maker 4.2 Script output

Tags: processmaker

I am working on process maker 4.2, and it is running on “localhost:8080”.
I created one script named as "practice1"[image: script screen (practice11)] , where I am returning a simple output i.e, return {"Hello": "Tryig by Devesh"};

How can I get the script output when I will call that endpoint using postman.
As of now I am using "http://localhost:8080/api/1.0/scripts/2" and my response code is 200 and the output which I am getting here is:- [image: postman output]

How can I get my script output ("Hello": "Tryig by Devesh") here instead of getting all the data ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be use the `POST` method in order to execute the script. The endpoint should be return a `key`; with this key, you can get the response of the script execution, using this another endpoint:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/1.0/scripts/execution/{key}
```